# Why do we need to use “would” in "I've got an acting job. Like you'd believe that."

Tags: meaning

Which is correct?

> I've got an acting job. Like you believe that.

or

> I've got an acting job. Like you'd believe that.

What's the difference between these two sentences?

Comment: **I've got an acting job** is a sentence. **Like you(d) believe that is a slang construction of uncertain meaning. Are you trying to say **Would you believe that?**

Comment: Like you believe or  would believe that. means: I don't think you believe or would believe that.

Answer (score 1):

There are some idiomatic phrases such as ***like you'd know!/like he'd ask!*** (where ***'d*** stands for ***would***). There is also the phrase ***like I care!***, which does not contain ***would***. These phrases are informal and are

> used to emphasize that something that has been suggested is not true
> or would never happen
>
> - They were asking me what I'd do if I won. ***Like that would ever happen***! ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/like-you-care-like-you-d-know-like-he-d-ask))

So in your second sentence, the speaker is pretty sure the person they are speaking to will (would) never believe what they just said.

Answer (score 0):

Is that also from the "Friends" series?
If so, which statement appeared in the series?

It sounds as if the speaker is expressing their fear that what they said would not be believed.

You could add some words to make it more understandable:

"I said that *like (as if) you would believe it*, but you may not."

The "would" expresses expectation or uncertainty. The statement makes more sense with "would".

You might get a better answer if you provide more context and a video link.